# Javascript window.open() with php code

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<?php
    $data=SOME_STRING;
    $url="http://SOME_WEBSITE.com/".$data; //$url is a valid website with the addition of data
?>
<input type="button" value="button" onClick="window.open(<?php echo $url;?>)" >
```

But nothing happens when I click on the button.

It does work when I replace the PHP `echo` with the precise url string but I want to be able to pass different urls.

1. Why doesn't it work?
2. Can you please think about alternative way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe you forgot quotes to surround the URL. window.open('<?php echo $url;?>')

Comment: Whenever running into Javascript problems, first forget about PHP, and just check your Javascript inside your browser. The Element Inspector is your friend there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need quotes:

```
<input type="button" value="button" onClick="window.open('<?php echo $url;?>')" />
```